# java ME creating your own layer

Tags: java-me, sprite, layer

Is it possible to create your own Layer?
like:

```
public class MyLayer extends javax.microedition.lcdui.game.Layer{
(...)
}
```

i get the error: "Layer() is not public in Layer; cannot be accessed from outside the package."

I wanted to draw some 2D graphics (import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics), and on top of that a Sprite coursor. Graphics are mostly still, so there's no need to draw them every time, so i thought layerManager will help me, but with that one i'd need it to be a Sprite or a TiledLayer. Creating my own Layer would solve the problem.

Comment: Did you import javax.microedition.lcdui.game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Layer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/Layer.html) is not designed for extension outside the `javax.microedition.lcdui.game` package. The error messages is clear about it.
But you may extend [`TiledLayer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/TiledLayer.html) or [`Sprite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/Sprite.html).

**Update**

As `paint` method on both classes is final (pointed by @[bartholomew-surma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2165777/bartholomew-surma) on comments) my above statement is invalid.
Another approach is to create a mutable [`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html), call `getGraphics` method, draw the 2D graphics in it and finally paint the sprite.

Comment: Both TiledLayer's and Sprite's paint methods are final, can't paint my Graphics with them.